# Logstash: how to reset everything

Tags: logstash

I'm new to Logstash and Elasticsearch.
After some tests I want to restart and make a new index.
However, I'm getting this:

```
root@imageoffice:/etc/logstash/conf.d# sudo -Hu root  /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/
Sending Logstash logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2019-04-22T17:00:04,910][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory.  If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting.
[2019-04-22T17:00:04,965][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

How can I simple reset everything and run the `sudo -Hu root  /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/` command succesfull?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that there's already a logstash running on your machine.  If you don't want the old one running, shut it down or kill it.

Typically, logstash is managed through a startup script (systemd, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Removed the .lock file from `bin/data` and the error was gone.